# UINavigationController.set​View​Controllers is resulting in an empty viewControllers array

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using the `set​View​Controllers` function on UINavigationController to set my first root view controller but the `viewControllers` array is empty after it has been called.

I know it is expected behavior to see the view controller in the `viewControllers` array immediately after setting, even if there is an animation so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

`setViewControllers([viewControllerToPresent], animated: true)`

Noteworthy: It is happening at app launch time but after I am certain the UINavigationController is loaded and ready.

Comment: Can we see some code, please?

Comment: Thanks for the attempted help. Its really hard to show any concise code for this. What it requires is a strong fundamental understanding of quirky UIKit behaviors. See my answer below if you know any more about why UIKit behaves this way. Cheers!

Comment: Even someone with a "strong fundamental understanding of quirky UIKit behaviors" can't read your mind and solve a problem that isn't fully explained. For example, your solution below mentions a modal being the issue, yet your question fails to note that modal presentation (let alone _multiple_ view controllers in play) was even part of the equation. A few lines of code can go a long way for those of us trying to help you. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @nickgraef thanks, and apologies if my tone came off snarky. The two parts that affected each other ended up being so far apart, I never would have known how to hint that right. But I did update my answer to include the one line that makes it clear this is an ANIMATED setViewControllers that failed, which is relevant. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being trying to simultaneously present a viewcontroller modally (tutorial slides) as the navigationcontroller was trying to push a viewcontroller on to the stack (both animated)

By delaying the presentation of the modals by 1 second, both view controllers were able to present without clobbering one another.

Would love to know the whys of this if anyone if familiar enough with UIKit and Animation APIs to explain. Will accept my own answer if I don't hear from anyone but will gladly change this if we get a better answer in the future.